# How can I change protrait mode of a fragment to landscape full screen videoview

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am using VideoView in a Fragment when I play the video I need it to be played in landscape mode with full screen and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In the fragment class add the following

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity != null) a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
    }
}
```